# Windows7: No disk usage in status bar?

Tags: windows-7, disk-space-utilization, windows-explorer

I am trying out Windows 7 RC, and one thing annoys me a bit. In windows XP (Can't remember how it was in Vista...) when browsing folders I could see how much free space I had on the disk in the status bar. On Windows 7, all I see is how many items are in the folder I am browsing. Can this be changed some how? Or is it just the way Windows 7 is?

Comment: It's a very thin line deciding which aspect of system configuration is sysadmin-related and which isn't... (changing a bit of UI -- off limits, changing a permission setting -- OK).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think you can change that with W7 alone.
That is the [same with Vista](http://www.techtalkz.com/windows-vista-all/23347-windows-explorer-status-bar.html), by the way.

At best you can show the [disk space of a folder on hover](http://malektips.com/vista-explorer-folder-size-hover.html).

Or you can click on "Computer" in an explorer: the right panel does display all drives with their respective free space.

Comment: I would rather like to have it visible all the time in the status bar like in xp, but oh well. can't get everything I guess =)